# Google Sheets API resulting in "GoogleAuth is not a constructor" error in Node

Tags: node.js, api, google-sheets

I've been trying to set up a node application with the Google Sheets API, but when initializing as per the documentation I get the following error:

TypeError: google.auth.GoogleAuth is not a constructor

Using the below code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: 'credentials.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
});
```

I've tried looking everywhere but haven't been able to find a solution.

To clarify I have installed googleapis with npm in the project as well

Comment: What version of googleapis are you using? Have you tried reinstalling your node_modules? You can try this to reinstall your modules: `rm -rf node_modules; rm package-lock.json; npm i`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same [problem](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1782) and updating the `googleapis` library fixed the issue. Run `npm i googleapis@latest` and try again.

Comment: This. Damn! their documentation is still in version 39. The latest version is 105 as I am writing this.